# Calculating Attendance with two days span

Tags: php, html, sql-server, fingerprint, biometrics

**Idea:**

i have a fingerprint machine that registers the employees attendance, 
but some of the employees have shifts and one of these shift occurs over two days, such that an employee check in at 11 PM (21/02/2018) and check out at 6 AM (22/02/2018) which is the next day. and all these data are registered in the database.

**Problem:**

the problem is that their shifts are variable, some times the employee 
come to work at 11 PM and get out at 6 AM the next day, and some time he come 3 PM and get out 11 PM in the same day, so when i look at the database and see a record with 11 PM i don't know if it belongs to the same day or the previous day, and i want to make an attendance report for their manager.

**Request:**

I need an advice on how to solve this problem, how does a places with similar situation solve this problem ?

**(UPDATE)**

**Sample Data:**

[image]

Comment: Why not just store the time _and_ the date?

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The OP actually didn't explicitly say he wasn't doing that, but yes date and time should be stored together.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Well, the OP wrote _"and see a record with 11 PM i don't know if it belongs to the same day or the previous day,"_. If both were stored, that would most likely not be an issue.

Comment: You are receiving down votes for not showing much effort (though perhaps you don't even know where to start), negating an otherwise generally good question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i do store the date and time, but that would not make a difference, because i'll see the 11PM with 22/02/2018 and still don't know if this is the end of the shift or the beginning of the second shift, which end at 6AM 23/02/2018 ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i wanted an advice or an idea, because i really don't know where to begin and this is my first time dealing with shifts :)

Comment: @suzy I gave you an option below.

Comment: So the issue is really about how you would now if a logged datetime means coming or going? You should really update your question, since that actually asks something else. Either way, you've gotten an answer that would help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes your data looks something like this:

```
EmployeeId | check_in            | check_out
1          | 2018-02-21 23:00:00 | 2018-02-22 06:00:00
```

You can report stats on each employee and day corresponding to the day when the employee checked in.  You could also report on the check out date, if you wanted to.  Assuming the former, you could try this query:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    CONVERT(date, check_in) AS check_in_date,
    DATEDIFF(hh, check_in, check_out) AS shift_length_in_hours
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I updated the question with sample data, please take a look

Comment: I don't like the idea of a single column for login and logout times.  For one thing, what happens if someone forgets to log out, or login?  I think two columns, with one record for each shift, is a much cleaner design.